# syntax error in INSERT INTO statement i tried everything nothing worked

Tags: vb.net

```
        Dim cmd9 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Insert into Order(CusName,Phone,SellerUsername,InternalID,OuterID,AccessoryID,InternalCount,OuterCount,AccessoryCount,TotalPrice) values(@CusName,@Phone,@SellerUsername,@InternalID,@OuterID,@AccessoryID,@InternalCount,@OuterCount,@AccessoryCount,@TotalPrice)", con)
        cmd9.Parameters.Clear()

        cmd9.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CusName", CusName)
        cmd9.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", Phone)
        cmd9.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SellerUsername", SellerUsername)
        cmd9.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InternalID", InternalID)
        cmd9.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OuterID", OuterCount)
        cmd9.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccessoryID", AccessoryID)
        cmd9.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InternalCount", InternalCount)
        cmd9.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OuterCount", OuterCount)
        cmd9.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccessoryCount", AccessoryCount)
        cmd9.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalPrice", TotalPrice)

        cmd9.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Any error messages that you are receiving?

Comment: You must provide the exact error message you received.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that `Order` is a reserved word, given that it is used in `ORDER BY` clauses. You would need to escape it, e.g. `"INSERT INTO [Order]..."`.